# Running NodeJS code in Tizen Studio?

Tags: node.js, requirejs, tizen, tizen-web-app, client-side-scripting

Is there any way to run the server-side `nodeJS` code in `Tizen-studio` ? I need to use the `dns` module of nodeJS and I can't get to use `require.js` for using the `dns` module in my client-side javascript code ? So, can someone suggest how to use a `node` module using `require.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://developer.tizen.org/blogs/stewartchristie/2013/running-node.js-on-tizen-2.0) Tutorial may help you to create and running NodeJS application on Tizen. Also follow this [thread](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/how-use-node.js-tizen).

[image]

Comment: I already saw this, but I can't run `sdb` in my shell. I can't understand the difference between `sdb` and `tizen-studio`.

Comment: It is a command line tool ... already installed with your Tizen Studio. 
https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/running-and-testing-your-app/sdb

Comment: https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.devtools/html/common_tools/smart_dev_bridge.htm#command

Comment: I can't get it running in linux ? Can you give a sample command to run it on a running emulator ?

Comment: It shows this error : `error: failed to close '/nodejs-0.6.14-slp.1.1.armv7l.rpm': Permission denied`

Comment: Set up Tizen Environment first .... follow this https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/developing-tizen-apps-tizen-studio